# url in css get rewritten with angular

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, svg, base-url

In angular there is an issue with having base set and html5mode with svgs. It causes all things like `filter: url(#url)` to be rewritten as `filter: url(/base/#url)`.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8934

I've tried disabling html5 mode and removing the base but whenever angular bootstraps it still rewrites the url.

While angular is loading if the svg is present it will show the correct clip/filter whatever however once angular initializes it's gone. Does anyone know a workaround? I've tried using the full file path before targeting it as well as using the disabling of base.

By having base set i mean 
`<base href='/'>` which works as it should.

Further inspection into this problem reveals that when angular is initialized it transforms the filter into an svg

### before angular

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g> 
    <path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

### after bootstrap

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <svg class='filter'> 
      <path>
    </svg>
  </defs>
  <g> 
   <path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "having base set" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being because we had a directive named filter...

A bad mistake on our part!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have set the wrong base attribute in the head of you index file.

> Be sure to check all relative links, images, scripts etc. Angular
>   requires you to specify the url base in the head of your main html
>   file () unless html5Mode.requireBase is set to
>   false in the html5Mode definition object passed to
>   $locationProvider.html5Mode(). With that, relative urls will always be
>   resolved to this base url, even if the initial url of the document was
>   different.

[Documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/guide/$location)

Comment: I've added more details in the post. It has nothing to do with base as it behaves the same with or without, also the path of the url inside chrome inspector is correct.